# Dlookup with date criteria query parameter?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query I want set query parameters from within for a [DLookup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285866):

Query **checkDate_Count_ForDangerousTickets:**

```
SELECT count(*) AS numRelatedTickets
FROM DangrousTicketList
WHERE DateValue(backUpDate)>=DateValue(StartDate) And DateValue(backUpDate)<=DateValue(EndDate)
GROUP BY backUpDate;
```

I call the query from `dlookup` setting the query parameter `backUpDate`:

```
DLookUp("[numRelatedTickets]", "[checkDate_Count_ForDangerousTickets]", _ 
"[backUpDate]=" & Format("01-27-2013", "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"))
```

And I get the error:

```
Run-time Error '2471'
The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 
'backUpDate'
```

It's as though the query parameter `backUpDate` is not being set for some reason.

Comment: If `checkDate_Count_ForDangerousTickets` is a parameter query you can't use it from `DLookup` unless you adapt the query to get its parameter value from a form, table, or custom VBA function.

Comment: @HansUp I've been tinkering around with this too, and I came to the same conclusion. I'm starting to think that a VBA function using a `QueryDef` object might be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on HansUp's comment and my own tinkering I believe you're going to have to use a little VBA function to run your parameter query:

```vbs
Public Function LookupDangerousTicketCount(backUpDate As Date) As Variant
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("checkDate_Count_ForDangerousTickets")
    qdf!backUpDate = backUpDate
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rst.BOF And rst.EOF Then
        LookupDangerousTicketCount = Null
    Else
        LookupDangerousTicketCount = rst!numRelatedTickets
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
End Function
```

Then instead of your `DLookup()` call you can just use

```
LookupDangerousTicketCount(#2013-01-27#)
```